# Error trying to install ionic app on android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

Could someone help me, I have a study project to deliver and when generating the APK and send to my Android device, I could not install.

- I already set permission to install from unknown sources
- Project Link: https://github.com/gugoan/tcc2019pucmg

The message below appears:

[image]

Comment: Hi! i've cloned the repo and got this error: Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

Comment: @BrianDucca But managed to generate the APK?

Comment: I don't remember this mistake occurring to me

Comment: Does it work when you run the it directly using `ionic cordova run android`? Try to install it using adb by `adb install APK_PATH`. You need to enable USB debugging on your device and connect it to your PC / Laptop

Comment: I didn't try to do it that way. Because I need to provide the APK to the teachers.

Comment: remove already installed the app in device with a same package name

Comment: Even if you can create app, you won't able to post data because you cant post data from the device to your localhost I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try building a signed apk.

First of all build a release apk using this.

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

Then run these commands in a command prompt. (Navigate to the folder where your apk is located)

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias
```

then,

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.jks your_apk_name.apk my-alias
```

Comment: While executing the command 'ionic cordova build android --prod --release', it displayed some errors, so I fixed them. thnx @koga

Answer (score 0):

If you have to provide the APK to teachers use a app like ***APK Extractor*** on your smartphone after a

> ionic cordova run android